# Llamar un método no estático en el main console con interfaz

Tags: c#

estoy teniendo una dificultad a la hora de consultar un método no estático desde un estático usando las interfaces.

Este es mi código

```
    public class Program
{
    private readonly IFormuleReportService _formuleReportService;
    private readonly IProgram _program;

    public Program(IFormuleReportService formuleReportService, IProgram program)
    {
        this._formuleReportService = formuleReportService;
        this._program = program;
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        this.SetFormuleReport(); // ACA EL PROBLEMA, this no se puede usar en static pero el main lo quiere
    }

    public void SetFormuleReport()
    {
       this._formuleReportService.SetFormuleReport("28156", 2019, 4);
    }

}
```

Alguna solución?

gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear una instancia de `Program` algo asi

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFormuleReportService formuleReportService = new ....;
    IProgram program = new ...;

    Program p = new Program(formuleReportService, program);
    p.SetFormuleReport(); 
}
```

No se cuales seran las implementaciones de las interfaces, por eso puse ..., pero  deberias cambiar eso por las clases concretas que implementan esas interfaces

Comment: public interface IFormuleReportService : IBaseService<FormuleReportDTO>
    {

        IList<FormuleReportModelDTO> GetFormuleReport(int clientid, int year, int? quarter);

        void SetFormuleReport(string clientid, int year, int quarter);
    }. De esta forma está construida la interfaz

Comment: bien, pero necesitas implementarla en clases para poder instanciarlas

Comment: Si ya en la interfaz tienen sus metodos ya creados, pero mi pregunta es, al hacer el  = new ... que instancio? ya lo único que necesitaria es pasar la inferfaz por parametro y ya.

Comment: mmm sabes lo que es una interface y un class ? la interface no se pasa por parametro, se pasa la instancia de una class que implementa esa interface. Recomendaria leas algo mas de programacion orientado a objetos. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming

Comment: Sigo sin entender... yo tengo claro la poo, y el tema de las interfaces. pero ahora estoy un poco perdido con lo de la instancia...

Comment: sabes la diferencia entre una interface y una class ? sino sabes responder esa pregunta entonces no tienes claro POO